# how to find specific html element pattern

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

A sample of my code:

```
<div id="ds">

    <classified_title check_zone="true" article="start" a_type="advertisement" cid="#P98_001"></classified_title>
    <p article_con="98.1" cid="#P98_005"></p>
    <p article="start" a_type="advertisement" cid="#P100_001"></p>
    <p article_con="98.1" cid="#P99_001"></p>
    <dc_title article="start" check_zone="true" a_type="article" cid="#P95_001"></dc_title>
    <pam_credit rot_ang="90_3021_1470_681_71" check_zone="true" article_con="95.1" cid="#P95_010">ILLUSTRATION BY HECTOR CADEMARTORI</pam_credit>
    <p article_con="95.1" link_para="95.1" cid="#P96_009"></p>
    <p article_con="95.1" link_para="96.1" cid="#P96_016"></p>
    <p article_con="95.1" link_para="96.1" cid="#P97_001"></p>
    <p article="end" cid="#P97_008"></p>

</div>
```

I want to distinguish sets of three, like the following code:

```
<p article_con="98.1" cid="#P98_005"></p>
<p article="start" a_type="advertisement" cid="#P100_001"></p>
<p article_con="98.1" cid="#P99_001"></p>
```

The first tag (`<p article_con="98.1" cid="#P98_005"></p>`) has an attribute `article_con` and second tag (`<p article="start" a_type="advertisement" cid="#P100_001"></p>`) has attribute `article="start"` and again third tag is like first tag, as the  `article_con` attribute has same value.

Not like that:

```
<p article_con="98.1" cid="#P98_005"></p>
<p article="start" a_type="advertisement" cid="#P100_001"></p>
<p article_con="98.2" cid="#P99_001"></p>
```

The first and third tag's article_con attribute value different, important thing is there must be `article="start"` attribute in second tag.

Comment: What about: `$( "p[article_con='98.1']" )` you check each element of the list (if the element at index +2 have same article_con value you use it)

Comment: $( "p[article_con='98.1'] + p[article='start']" ) would hit the "middle" one

Comment: So in this large section of code you are working with, there will be a number of these group of 3 tags like as you describe? Three `p` tags in a row with `article_con`, then `article`, followed by ,`article_con` where the `_con` number is the same. Is that right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with @Bluehound that you should reformat your HTML, but in case you can't do this here is my plain JS suggestion:

```
var findArticle = function() {
    var start = document.querySelectorAll('[article="start"]')
    var l = start.length
    for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        var node = start[i]
        var prev = node.previousElementSibling
        if (!prev || !prev.hasAttribute('article_con')) continue
        var con = prev.getAttribute('article_con')
        var next = node.nextElementSibling
        if (!next || !next.hasAttribute('article_con') ||
            next.getAttribute('article_con') != con) continue
        return node
    }
    return null
}

var article = findArticle()
console.log(article)
```

example code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/79qLzubo/)

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would do:

```
<div id="98.1">
    <p cid="#P98_005"></p>
    <p article="start" a_type="advertisement" cid="#P100_001"></p>
    <p cid="#P99_001"></p>
</div>
```

If you wrap each set of 3 in a div and set its `id` attribute to the article_con number, then you can easily access the div and thus its children by that id using:

```
<script>
    var childrenArray = document.getElementById('98.1').childNodes;
</script>
```

From there you can access the first, second, or third paragraph from that array.